# How can I loop a sequelize response

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, sequelize.js

If I make a request to a Postgres database with Sequelize, I get the next result:

```
 [
  Tags {
    dataValues: { idtag: 18 },
    _previousDataValues: { idtag: 18 },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions: {
      ...
    },
    _options: {
      ...
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  Tags {
    dataValues: { idtag: 19 },
    _previousDataValues: { idtag: 19 },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions: {
      ...
    },
    _options: {
      ...
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  },
  Tags {
    dataValues: { idtag: 20 },
    _previousDataValues: { idtag: 20 },
    _changed: {},
    _modelOptions: {
      ...
    },
    _options: {
      ...
    },
    isNewRecord: false
  }
]
```

I can't find the way to loop this to can get the 'idtag' values.
I tried to parse this to JSON with JSON.stringify() but it gives me a string. Also, I tried to loop this like it was an array but it didn't works too.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of what you want to achieve?

Comment: try ```.toJSON()``` instead ```JSON.stringify```

Comment: like this : ```let result = FetchedResultArrayWithSequelize.map(item=>item.toJSON());```

Comment: Also you can set ```plain : true``` option in sequelize query. It will return plain object.

Comment: Finally I used JSON.stringify() and then JSON.parse() and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finilly I have the answer. First I converted the result with JSON.stringify() and then with JSON.parse().

```
let tags = await models.Tags.findAll({ attributes: ['idtag'], where: { iduser: iduser } });

let string = JSON.stringify(tags);
tags = JSON.parse(string);
```

And finally, to loop:

```
tags.forEach(async (tag) => {
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your output is stored to an array. Now using following piece of code you can collect idTag values.

```
const idTagVals = [];
array.forEach(element => {
    idTagVals.push(element.dataValues.idtag);
});
console.log(idTagVals); //[ 18, 19, 20 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to sequelize [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html)

```
  TagsModel.findAll({where: {} ,plain:true});
```

Will return Array of plain objects.